# Is there a more efficent way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

How can I achieve this code easier or with less lines of code?
I'm curious if it can be done easier and/or more efficently. Because I feel like there is too much repetition in this, so there must be an easy way.
And I'm not only planning to make 4 of this but like 20-30, so performance is a key aspect.

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#q1" ).click(function() {
            $( "#a1" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
            if ($(this).hasClass('on')){
                    $(this).removeClass('on');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('on');
            }
        });
        $( "#q2" ).click(function() {
            $( "#a2" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
            if ($(this).hasClass('on')){
                    $(this).removeClass('on');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('on');
            }
        });
        $( "#q3" ).click(function() {
            $( "#a3" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
            if ($(this).hasClass('on')){
                    $(this).removeClass('on');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('on');
            }
        });
        $( "#q4" ).click(function() {
            $( "#a4" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
            if ($(this).hasClass('on')){
                    $(this).removeClass('on');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('on');
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="faq_content">
  <div class="faq_box">
    <div class="questions" id="q1">
      <span>xyz</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answers" id="a1">
      <span>xyz</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq_box">
    <div class="questions" id="q2">
      <span>xyz</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answers" id="a2">
      <span>xyz</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) might be of interest

Comment: If your code works, and you want to make it more efficient, then you may want to ask over on [codereview.se]; if you're getting errors when running this code then that would be on topic here, but you'd need to explain the errors you're getting. I'm also interested in the "*comma separated stuff*" that you tried, what did that do, and how exactly did it break? Are you able to share enough of your "*[mcve]*" code that we can reproduce your problem(s)?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica My code works, sorry if it's not the right place to ask then.. What I mentioned is this: $( "#q1,#q2,#q3,#q4" ).click(function() {
    $( "#a1" ).slideToggle();
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')){
      $(this).removeClass('on');
    }else{
     $(this).addClass('on');
    }
   });

Comment: No real problem, there seems to be an overlap between the two communities anyway (though I don't participate there). As regards your code, could you edit that into your question, and explain how it failed or didn't work? Also, please post your relevant HTML and CSS relating to your problem(s). In order to edit your question there's an [edit] link just below the tags in your question, or you can use the one here in this comment.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica My problem is almost solved with help of Kai. But I should probably still edit the question to be useful for others, and maybe someone knows a better solution. Thank you for this helpful community. I will wait a little with accepting as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that I can think of, given your HTML structure, is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // selecting all the elements you need to work with,
  // and binding the anonymous function of the click()
  // method as the event-handler:
  $("#q1, #q2").click(function() {

    // here $(this) will refer to the element that fired the
    // click event, from that element:
    $(this)
      // we navigate to the next-sibling element matching the
      // supplied selector:
      .next('.answers')
      // we use the slideToggle() method to show/hide the element,
      // using an Arrow function to compose the anonymous
      // function so that we can use the same this (and therefore
      // $(this)) as the outer function:
      .slideToggle('slow', () => {

        // here $(this) still refers to the clicked element, as
        // Arrow functions don't establish their own 'this'; and
        // we use the toggleClass() method to add, or remove, the
        // supplied class based on whether it already exists on
        // the element:
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
    });

  // here we again call the click() method, without arguments, in
  // order to fire the click event on page-load (which, in this
  // context will cause the answers to be hidden on page-load):
  }).click();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#q1, #q2").click(function() {
    $(this).next('.answers').slideToggle('slow', () => {
      $(this).toggleClass('on');
    });
  }).click();
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.faq_box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.2em auto;
  width: 80vw;
}

.questions {
  background-color: #ffff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
}

.questions::before {
  content: attr(id) ': ';
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.answers::before {
  content: attr(id) ': ';
}

.on {
  background-color: #0f06;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faq_content">
  <div class="faq_box">
    <div class="questions" id="q1">
      <span>xyz</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answers" id="a1">
      <span>xyz</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faq_box">
    <div class="questions" id="q2">
      <span>xyz</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answers" id="a2">
      <span>xyz</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`slideToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

Comment: Yes, this is the easiest and shortest one! I didn't expect my code to be 7 lines :). Thank you! The last click didn't even need because I already hid the answers with css.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped, and my sincere thanks for the compliment! As for your hope for finding shorter solutions in future, you will. So long as you practice, follow blogs or YouTube tutorials, ask or answer questions here that's all that's required: practice. Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var qClasses = $('.q');
    
    qClasses.on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var aIds =  $this.data('id');

        $(aIds).slideToggle("slow");

        $this.toggleClass("on");
    });

});
```

Since all the #q1,#q2... are doing the same thing on click you can utilize the classes for this and with `<div id="#q1" class="q" data-id="#a1" ></div>` you can refer to the id on click of the q classes. Also, you can define the initial state of #q1 or q classes as there are only two states with class "on" or without it so the default state can be defined directly in HTML instead of checking in the JS. like: `<div id="#q1" class="q on" data-id="#a1"></div>`

Comment: Although I the #a1,2,3,4 are another divs, I can maybe make it work with this help. I will make it 1 div probably. Thank you, I will experiment with these and return with results tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Because all your handlers look the same, you can create a function which returns a function:

```js
  function createHandler(selector) {
     return function() {
            $( selector ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
            if ($(this).hasClass('on')){
                    $(this).removeClass('on');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('on');
            }
        }
  }
```

and use it like this:

```js
   $( "#q1" ).click(createHandler("#a1"))
```

To find out more about this principle search for "Higher-Order Functions" and "Closures"

Comment: This exactly did what I wanted, Thanks!